# React bootstrap dropdown form control layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im new to react (and react bootstrap) frontend and im a bit stuck. Is there a way to use a dropdown like this and have the 2 date inputs next to eachother (horizontally) instead of vertically? Orcan i only achieve that by using accordion? It needs to look like a dropdown before you click it.

This is how it looks now. And as you see it isnt quite fancy.

[image: Picture of current layout]

My current code:

```
 return (
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" style={ buttonStyle } id="dropdown-basic" className="uniform-select" >
                {headerTitle} 
            </Dropdown.Toggle>         
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Form.Control
                    type="date"
                    name="startTime"
                    id="startDateId"
                    onChange={ handleStartDate }
                />
                <Form.Control
                    type="date"
                    name="enddate"
                    id="endDateiD"
                    onChange={ handleEndDate }
                />
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    )
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, im quite new too but you can probably change the flexbox properties, from a column to a row, if you havent tried it. just inspect the DOM element, and create a new css style with the classname and experiment with the flex directions, cause as far as i know most of react bootstrap components use flex anyways